# How to add map column in spark based on other column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have this table:

```
|Name|Val|
|----|---|
|Bob |1  |
|Marl|3  |
```

And I want to transform it to a map with single element like this:

```
|Name|Val|MapVal|
|----|---|------|
|Bob |1  |(0->1)|
|Marl|3  |(0->3)|
```

Any idea how to do it in scala?
I couldn't find any way to build a map in `withColumn` statement...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it - Just need to include the implicit sql:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

And then use the `map` function:
`df.withColumn("MapVal", map(lit(0), col("Val")))`