# How to add custom strings to legend of count_value plots in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe column on which I applied `value_counts` to find number of occurances of each entity.

I am trying to plot it as a bar graph. 
It plot with each entity on the x-axis and their count on y-axis. How can I add a legend so that each entity on x axis will be mapped to a string.

The result of the `value_counts` is like this:

```
df.Column.value_counts()

10.0      1094
2154.0     697
23.0       202
```

I need a legend which will replace my entities with strings.

- 10 - Alpha
- 2154 - Beta
- 23 - Gamma

The number of entities may vary. I have a list of strings for each entity. So I am looking to replace my entities by strings from the list. I want to replace it only on the legend.

The graph should have entities on x-axis and the legend should have equivalent strings from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Not so easy, because by default no legend:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = df.Column.value_counts()
#sample data
#s = pd.Series([1094,697,202], index=[10.0,2154.0,23.0])

s.plot.bar()
a = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Alpha')
b = mpatches.Patch(color='orange', label='Beta')
c = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='Gamma')

plt.legend(handles=[a,b,c], loc='best')

plt.show()
```

If wnt also change values of `axis x` add `rename`:

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = df.Column.value_counts()
d = {10:'Alpha', 2154: 'Beta', 23: 'Gamma'}
#sample data 
#s = pd.Series([1094,697,202], index=[10.0,2154.0,23.0])

s.rename(d).plot.bar()

a = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Alpha')
b = mpatches.Patch(color='orange', label='Beta')
c = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='Gamma')

plt.legend(handles=[a,b,c], loc='best')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
equiv = {10:"Alpha", 2154:"Beta", 23:"Gamma"}
df = df.map(equiv)
```

or may have to use .withColumn and something like this [How to add map column in spark based on other column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466708/how-to-add-map-column-in-spark-based-on-other-column)